# Div is not resizing right to contained image on grid

Tags: html, css

i have an issue with css and html.
Im designing my website with an grid.
The problem takes place on the upper left one.

The grid is 2x2 and the upper one height resize to max-content,
the upper left one width resize also to max-content.
The rest resize to 1fr.

Now i got an "wrapper" div which contains an image (logo) in the upper left one.

The problem is, that if i reload the page with cache or if i redirect onto it, the image doesnt show up.
If i reload it with Shift + F5, the image shows up!

The code is the following:

```
<div class="main">
    <div class="menu">
        <div class="image">
            <img id="logo" src="images/logo.png">
        </div>
        <div class="submenu">
            <li>
                <a href="index.php?title=main"><h1>Startseite</h1></a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="index.php?title=exam&do=main"><h1>Prüfung</h1></a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="index.php?title=result"><h1>Ergebnisse</h1></a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="index.php?title=admin"><h1>Verwaltung</h1></a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="index.php?title=login&logout=1"><h1>Logout</h1></a>
            </li>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="content">
        <div class="data">
            *Should not care (works fine, extra grid is placed here too)*
        </div>
        <div class="personal">
            *Should not care (works fine)*
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

The CSS is the following:

```
.main {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr;
  grid-template-rows: max-content 1fr;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.menu {
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.4);
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: max-content 1fr;
    grid-template-rows: 1fr;
    gap: 0px 0px;
    grid-area: 1 / 1 / 2 / 2;
}

.image{
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
}

.image #logo{
    max-width: 100%;
    max-height: 100%;
}

.submenu {
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    min-width: 85%;
    grid-area: 1 / 2 / 2 / 3;
}

.submenu li{
    margin-left: 3%;
    margin-right: 3%;
    float: left;
}

.submenu a{
    font-family: "Franklin Gothic Medium";
    font-style: normal;
    font-variant: normal;
    font-weight: 700;
    color: white;
    text-decoration: none;
    float: left;
}

.content {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 1fr 0.2fr;
    grid-template-rows: 1fr;
    gap: 0px 0px;
    grid-area: 2 / 1 / 3 / 2;
}

.data {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr;
  grid-template-rows: 1fr 1fr;
  gap: 1px 1px;
  grid-area: 1 / 1 / 2 / 2;
}

.personal {
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
    grid-area: 1 / 2 / 2 / 3;
    padding-left: 5%;
    padding-right: 5%;
}
```

I thought of the 'image' div is not resizing right to its content 'logo' but couldnt get it fixed, does anybody have any thoughts?

Greetings